# FTS non-latin: text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm trying to use Full Text Search with Chinese characters using a postgres (9.6.1) FTS extension [ZHParser](https://github.com/amutu/zhparser).

Following some of the [examples here](http://francs3.blog.163.com/blog/static/405767272015065565069/), I wanted to select my `title` column and match the title `to_tsvector` to the query string `to_tsquery` with:

```
select title from table1 where 
to_tsvector('testzhcfg',title) @@ to_tsquery('testzhcfg','饭'); // 饭　 ＝ rice
```

**table1** schema:

```
id  | title   
--------------
1   | 饭     
2   | 吃饭    
3   | 我喜欢吃饭 
4   | 谢谢    
5   | 淘气
```

This gives:

```
NOTICE:  text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored
 title 
-------
(0 rows)
```

I expected results:

```
rows: 

title   
-----
饭     
吃饭    
我喜欢吃饭
```

Since 饭 (rice) is present in each.

[This article talks about the issue](https://mozillazg.com/2015/11/postgresql-full-text-search-search-chinese-notice-text-search-query-contains-only-stop-words-or-doesn-t-contain-lexemes-ignored.html), and recommends ensuring UTF8 encoded DB. I've ensured the table is UTF8:

```
mydatabase=# \l
                                             List of databases
      Name      |     Owner      | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |         Access privileges         
----------------+----------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------------------
 mydatabase     | myname         | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/myname               +
                |                |          |             |             | myname=CTc/myname
```

What other configurations need to be made to allow FTS to work with non-latin, specifically Chinese, characters?

---

Even more, if I search through the stop words of the configurations in `/usr/local/share/postgresql/tsearch_data`, I do not see 饭 listed.

Comment: Hi, have you installed zhparser for postgres?

Comment: Check that database  UTF8 code for `rice` and code for `rice` you type in are the same. Have you considered using UTF16 instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643694/utf-8-vs-unicode